# com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveApi.ContentsResult cannot be resolved... But everything else can be?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I'm getting this error:

```
 com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveApi.ContentsResult cannot be resolved
```

But just with that one import. These all work:

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Contents;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveFile;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveFolder.DriveFileResult;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.MetadataChangeSet;
```

And for some reason ContentsResult can't be found. Even doing this works:

```
 import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveApi.*;
```

And it works in the sense that it doesn't error on the import, but when I do that, ContentsResult still just cannot be found...

Has anyone had this issue before?

Answer (score 2):

There is no `ContentsResult` class in the DriveApi package, but there is a `DriveContentsResult` class:

```
com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveApi.DriveContentsResult
```

See http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/package-summary.html

Answer (score 1):

The answer 'myanimal' gave you is correct. You are probably using some older version of GDAA code, since  'ContentsResult' used to be there [see here](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/commit/f7c695060e8ac00d2b1cc7d8b6e565871c04d2ec). Please make also sure you are compiling with the latest 'play-services:6.5.87'. I'm not sure it you are using Android Studio. If yes, see if your 'build.gradle' config file has the  dependencies right:

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
  compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v2-rev105-1.17.0-rc'
  compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.17.0-rc') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.google-play-services'
  }
  ....
  ....
}
```

Disclaimer: *It is not a 'better' answer, just an extension of "myanimal's" answer below.*