# Error com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveApi.DriveContentsResult cannot be resolved

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I am working on Android Google Drive. As of now I am using the github sample code [Android Demos](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos). I am getting an error of

> The import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveApi.DriveContentsResult
>   cannot be resolved

and

> The import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveContents cannot be
>   resolved

I am using the updated Google play service and I have imported it properly.

I am using eclipse

Comment: Just try to re import googleplay services or you can see [this](http://quabr.com/28254196/com-google-android-gms-drive-driveapi-contentsresult-cannot-be-resolved-but-e)

Comment: Try to read my question properly  Joan Colmenero. I have asked for DriveContentsResult NOT ContentsResult. And yea what you told i already tried...it wont work

Comment: Dont down vote this question as not useful..I have researched pretty well. Unless you know the exact answer or same repeated question

Comment: Isn't it the same problem as discussed here?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28254196/com-google-android-gms-drive-driveapi-contentsresult-cannot-be-resolved-but-e  You may be using old code with a new version of GooPlaySvcs.

Comment: OOPS, I meant 'new code with an old version of library'

Comment: @JoanColmenero I don't quite understand why you're pointing us to 'QUABR' only to show the answer scraped from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
The import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveApi.DriveContentsResult cannot be resolved
```

and

```
The import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveContents cannot be resolved
```

This occur when we use old Google play service library and new code. Just delete the old library, download new Google play service library if you don't have and import the library to your workspace.

When you do like this, if you are using

```
import com.google.android.gms.drive.events.DriveEvent.Listener
```

Then change the line to

```
import com.google.android.gms.drive.events.ChangeListener;
```

Because Listener became ChangeListener in the new lib, and make corresponding changes in the code.

Answer (score 2):

I remember using 'ContentsResult' in GooPlaySvcs 6.1.+  and switching to 'DriveContentsResult' after installing GooPlaySvcs 6.5.+, So, I'm assuming you have 6.1.+ or older. Correct GooPlaySvcs lib for 'DriveContentsResult' is **'6.5.+'**, aka **'Rev. 22'** in Android SDK Manager:

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
  compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v2-rev105-1.17.0-rc'
  compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.17.0-rc') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.google-play-services'
  }
  ....
  ....
}
```

*It is also known as 'pulling the rug out (from under someone)'*

Comment: Thanks @seanpj. I was using old google_play_service library. I deleted the old library and imported new google_play_service. Now its working