# Android Google changeListener

Tags: android, google-play-services, changelistener

I am trying to run Android Google Drive. I am using the github sample code Android Demos.

I have added google play services to my project. This is the error Iam getting:

```
The import com.google.android.gms.drive.events.DriveEvent.ChangeListener cannot be resolved
```

After reading this page ([Error com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveApi.DriveContentsResult cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28405205/error-com-google-android-gms-drive-driveapi-drivecontentsresult-cannot-be-resolv))

I changed it to

```
The import com.google.android.gms.drive.events.ChangeListener
```

But, the error still exists within those two methods:

```
Listener cannot be resolved to a type
```

-

```
private void toggle() {
        if (mSelectedFileId == null) {
            return;
        }
        synchronized (mSubscriptionStatusLock) {
            DriveFile file = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(getGoogleApiClient(),
                    mSelectedFileId);
            if (!isSubscribed) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Starting to listen to the file changes.");
                file.addChangeListener(getGoogleApiClient(), changeListener);//error
                isSubscribed = true;
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Stopping to listen to the file changes.");
                file.removeChangeListener(getGoogleApiClient(), changeListener);//error
                isSubscribed = false;
            }
        }
        refresh();
    }
```

-

```
final private Listener<ChangeEvent> changeListener = new Listener<ChangeEvent>() {//error
    @Override
    public void onEvent(ChangeEvent event) {
        mLogTextView.setText(String.format("File change event: %s", event));
    }
};
```

Can anybody enlighten me on this issue?

Github code
https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this code:

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveApi;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveResource;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.events.ChangeEvent;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.events.ChangeListener;

PendingResult<DriveApi.DriveIdResult> pendingResult = Drive.DriveApi.fetchDriveId(mGoogleApiClient, id);
    pendingResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveIdResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull DriveApi.DriveIdResult driveIdResult) {
            if (!driveIdResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                Log.d(TAG, String.format("fetch drive id error: %s", driveIdResult.getStatus().getStatusMessage()));
                return;
            }
            mCurrentDriveId = driveIdResult.getDriveId();
            DriveResource resource = mCurrentDriveId.asDriveResource();
            Log.d(TAG, "received driveid from id");

            PendingResult<Status> pendingChange = resource.addChangeListener(mGoogleApiClient, new ChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChange(ChangeEvent changeEvent) {
                    onResourceChange(changeEvent);
                }
            });
            pendingChange.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                    if (status.isSuccess()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "change listener success");
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, String.format("change listener error: %s", status.getStatusMessage()));
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

But it looks like the changes are not too much realtime.
Anyway getFile() is obsolete.